# How to make foreach function in jquery asynchronous?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx-webparts, promises

I am trying to make each function of jquery asynchronous...In sharepoint framework, I am trying to update each line item of HTML table to sharepoint list using PnP JS Core library. For this I am trying below code:

```
 var itemID :any= $.when(async (result: number): Promise<any> => {
    var data = await getItemID();
    result = data[0].ID;
    return result;
}).then(() =>{
web.lists.getByTitle("TravelRequestDetails").items.getById(itemID).update({
   "Cost": cost
    })
  })
```

In the above code getItemID() is not getting called and then is executed due to which itemID is coming 'undefined'....

Please suggest any workaround for the same...

Comment: is this a javascript or React webpart?

Comment: javascript webpart

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a async function and later invoking it

```
async function doSomething(){
//....do something
var result = await getItemID();
 return result[0].ID 
}

//some
var itemID = await doSomething()
```